# Scrolling changes the order of the Dynamic Cells in a Table - Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Table View Controller that serves as a Review Order screen which basically has some cells with static content (such as headers) and other cells with dynamic content (such as a list of the services selected on previous views). The issue I am having is that if I scroll up to get to the bottom of my view and then scroll up again to see the top, I noticed the order of the dynamic cells changes.

**For example:**

When the view first renders I see the list of services in the order below:
**1) Manicure**
**2) Pedicure**
**3) 30 Minute Sauna**
[image]

But then, if I scroll down and up again, I see the following:
**1) 30 Minute Sauna**
**2) Pedicure**
**3) Manicure**
[image]

Below is the code to render each cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            //static header cell
            self.index = 0
            let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("headerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            return headerCell

        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            //static instruction cell
            self.index = 0
            let instructionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("instructionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            return instructionCell

        } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            //static services section header cell
            self.index = 0
            let servicesSectionHeaderCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("servicesSectionHeaderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            return servicesSectionHeaderCell

        } else if ((indexPath.row <= (self.services.count + 2)) && (indexPath.row > 2) && !self.services.isEmpty) {
            //dynamic service cells
            let serviceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("serviceCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ServiceCell
            serviceCell.serviceLabel.text = self.services[self.index]
            self.index += 1
            return serviceCell

        } else if (indexPath.row == (self.services.count + 3)) {
            //static appointment time section header cell
            self.index = 0
            let appointmentTimeSectionHeaderCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("appointmentTimeSectionHeaderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            return appointmentTimeSectionHeaderCell
        } else if (indexPath.row == (self.services.count + 4)) {
            //static date and time cell
            self.index = 0
            let dateAndTimeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dateAndTimeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DateAndTimeCell
            dateAndTimeCell.dateAndTimeLabel.text = self.orderReview.serviceDate + SINGLE_WHITE_SPACE_STRING_CONSTANT + self.orderReview.serviceTime
            return dateAndTimeCell
        } else {
            //default cell
            self.index = 0
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might be helpful to split the tableview into different sections with no space between them. That way you don't have the fragility of manual index management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the use of `self.index`. Its value appears to be dependent on the order that `cellForRow` is being called. That simply won't work.

Get rid `self.index` and base the index on the value of `indexPath`.

```
} else if ((indexPath.row <= (self.services.count + 2)) && (indexPath.row > 2) && !self.services.isEmpty) {
    //dynamic service cells
    let serviceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("serviceCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ServiceCell
    serviceCell.serviceLabel.text = self.services[indexPath.row - 3]

    return serviceCell
```

Comment: thanks! I see where I made it more complicated than it had to be. Those late nights, tsk.